# Illustrator Vector in Pygame/Python

Tags: python, vector, pygame

I do not know if this is doable but I am making a program in pygame and wanted to know if I could change the color of a vector file from python/pygame. I have a color wheel and would like to know if the user can use the selected color on an image. Is there another file format that makes this possible? Thanks.

Edit:

I found svgwrite, but how could I change to color of the SVG. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what " I have a color wheel and would like to know if the user can use the selected color on an image" means.

Comment: It is kind of hard to explain. If I have an image, how can I change the color of the image from python?

Comment: Images can contain many colors, which ones do you want to change?

Comment: No, my image that I want to change is single colored. So it starts off as green, but I want to change this image to any color from python.

Comment: Image files are composed of many dots or pixels, which can range in size from one-bit-per-pixel to several bytes for each one. What file format is the image in? You'll probably need to be able to read and change it, so that information is essential.

Comment: It is an ai file. I can use any format that works.

Comment: Ahh, an ai file isn't what most call an image file per se, it's a vector graphics file format which is a different sort of beast. The current ai file format is proprietary, so I doubt you can read it or that there's a Python module out there than can do it for you. Your best bet would be to use SVG format file, which is well documented open source standard (and there's probably a Python module to read (and/or write) one). If you can read one you can translate the vector definitions into equivalent pygame graphics and change colors if you wish. I think Adobe Illustrator and read and save them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your best bet is to store the image you want to "tint" as a grayscale bitmap, and then use a line like this to "tint" it in whatever direction you want:

```
surface.fill(color, special_flags=BLEND_RGB_MULT)
```

An alternative method would be to use a [palette](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_palette) (old-school!) for your image, and have the user pick the palette.